# Can the -> operator used with structure pointers be used for union pointers as well?

Tags: c

Suppose I have the follow code

```
union test
{
int salary[10];
short ages[20];
} *ptr;
```

Then can I point to the 2nd element of the salary as `ptr->salary[1]`? Or I use `ptr.salary[1]`?

Comment: Yes, `ptr->salary[1]` or `(*ptr).salary[1]` are correct. No, `ptr.salary[1]` is not correct, that's asking for a member in something neither a struct nor a union (namely a pointer).

Comment: I never knew the `(*ptr).salary[1]` syntax for structures or arrays!!can you kindly tell me why that works? Isn't `*ptr` supposed to mean `value at pointer`?

Comment: @TSingh: precisely. And the type of the value at that location is a union/struct, so you can use it as such.

Comment: Yes, `(*ptr)` is the value `ptr` points to, in this case a `union test` value. Then you can access its members using the `.`.

Comment: What did your compiler report when you tried to build it?

Comment: @FatalError Oh, I guess you mean before we use that pointer to point to elements inside a union/structure, we first assign it the address of a structure or union variable ? I completely missed that.Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

The usage `ptr.salary[1]` is incorrect as `ptr` is still the pointer independently on the type that it points to.

The correct way is:

```
ptr->salary[1]
```

or

```
(*ptr).salary[1]
```

In the second case do not forget the `()` as `*` has lower priority than `.`.

Comment: Daniel said `(*ptr).salary[1]`

Comment: That's only a partial answer to the question. You're correct that `ptr.salary[1]` is incorrect, but you don't say that the `->` operator is valid for pointers to unions as well as pointers to structs.